# Performance difference between passing a variable to the function and list to the function

Tags: c#, performance

```
void MyFunc(int var) 
{
    // Some Code
}

void MyFunc(List<int> varList) 
{
    // Some Code
}
```

What is the performance of parameter passing to these two functions?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: It is `Some Code` that consumes the time, not `4` or `8` bytes passed by CPU register (or by stack is the worst case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There answer is, there should be little difference.

- The first is allocating an `int` and copying the value type of a `int`,
- The second is allocating an reference and copying a reference (which for all intents-and-purposes is an `uint` / `ulong`)

There is no appreciable difference.

However, the bigger problem is why you are care about these micro-optimisations, i think you are over thinking this. You can always test this for your self. Either look at the *jitted* *asm*, or download *BenchmarkDotNet* and run a performance test